# Downloading Expansion File using DownloaderClientMarshaller not working

Tags: android, download, apk-expansion-files

I am attempting to integrate the `SampleDownloader` provided for Google Play into my code. I am using fragments and I call the the following statement from my fragment

```
"mDownloaderClientStub = DownloaderClientMarshaller.CreateStub
                ((IDownloaderClient) getActivity(), GrooveBassDownloaderService.class);".
```

I don't get any errors, but the file doesn't download either. I do get a button on my display to pause the download. When I click the button, I get the following error:

```
09-06 01:58:04.123: E/AndroidRuntime(21862): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-06 01:58:04.123: E/AndroidRuntime(21862):    at com.ssowens.groovebass.DownloaderFragment$1.onClick(DownloaderFragment.java:197)
```

I have tried trying to get the download to run from a `fragmentactivity` and was unsuccessful. I tried running the `sampledownloader` and I did get feed back, but not a downloaded file. I don't get feedback when I implement it into my code. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. This is my first time working with downloading expansion files and only my 3rd app.

Comment: Check if your button is not null and then check if you are getting any images/files from your downloader.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The DownloaderClient had not been started.

Comment: and where do you start it?